# Lost "\n (quotes and newline sequence) from servlet returned text

Tags: gwt, servlets, gwt-platform, guice-servlet

I'm returning some text from a servlet, which is working well, except for lines ending with a " character. Those lines causes the quotes and following newline character to get lost.
Do you have any ideas what could cause or fix this problem?

Comment: are you escaping `"` and `\n` characters

Comment: Thanks for the advise, it was caused by a malformed regex.